# ngOptions group complex object

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to display a select with ngOptions generated from this json:

```
{
  exceptions: [
    {
      card_issuer: {
        name: 'HSBC'
      },
      payer_costs: [
        {
          installments: 1
        },
        {
          installments: 2
        },
        {
          installments: 3
        }
      ]
    }
    ... another issuer
  ]
}
```

So, I have an array of card_issuer each with a sub array of payer_costs.

So far, I came up with this select:

```
<select ng-model = "exception" ng-options="exception.payer_costs as exception.payer_costs[0].installments group by exception.card_issuer.name for exception in exceptions"></select>
```

As you can see, I'm grouping by exception.card_issuer.name, and that's ok. The problem is the content of the group, that should be exception.payer_costs.installments (a list of installments for each card issuer. As I did't find the solution, in this example I used exception.payer_costs[0].installments, to display the 1nst element of payer_costs.

Do you know a way to show all payer_costs for each group?.

Comment: OFF Topic: Take a look at https://github.com/lordfriend/nya-bootstrap-select. Its very feature rich and easy to use.

Comment: @Shervin, looks nice. Sadly I'm using Zurb's Foundation and nya looks like needs Bootstrap. BTW, I'm sure the problem can be solved using AngularJS.